# What does 'claims' mean in the following text from Bernard Shaw "Maxims for Revolutionists"

Tags: meaning

I can't make sense of the following text from Bernard Shaw "Maxims for Revolutionists"
from Man and Superman (1903):

What does 'claims' mean in the following text:

> Excess of insularity makes a Briton an Imperialist.
>
> Excess of local self-assertion makes a colonist an Imperialist.
>
> A colonial Imperialist is one who raises colonial troops, equips a
> colonial squadron, **claims a Federal Parliament sending its
> measures to the Throne instead of to the Colonial Office**, and, being
> finally brought by this means into insoluble conflict with the insular
> British Imperialist, “cuts the painter” and breaks up the Empire.

I have 2 versions:

1. Does it mean that a colonial Imperialist claims **for himself** a Federal Parliament sending its measures to the Throne instead of to the Colonial Office? In other words, a colonial Imperialist claims that a Federal Parliament stopped sending its measures to the Throne and started to send them to the Colonial Office.
2. Or does it mean that a colonial Imperialist **demands** a Federal Parliament to send its measures to the Throne instead of to the Colonial Office?

Comment: Considering there was never a 'Federal Parliament' (which would be necessary for your first meaning) I would favour the second.

Comment: Depending on Shaw's wider context that's not necessarily true. Australia has and has had a federal parliament. I read it as a colonist who claims the right to have/form/establish a Federal Parliament. That Parliament would communicate with the British throne rather than the Colonial Office, and the country would thereby be acting as an independent sovereign nation.

Comment: Thank you, Peter Kirkpatrick. That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Shaw was talking in a wider Imperial (British Empire) sense, and not about any Australian colony's Federal Parliament.